# Waiting for Function to return value

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my application I need to call a function, which in turns call many functions. The problem is that I called the `getweather` function and it starts the `startprocess` and after that the process is completed. The `processCompleted` method is called by the `rssparser` and the value is available at the end of the `processCompleted` method.

```
-(void) getWeather: (NSDictionary *) dictionary {
    _rssParser = [[BlogRssParser alloc]init];
    self.rssParser.address = addressInterestedIn;
    self.rssParser.delegate = self;
    [[self rssParser]startProcess];
}

//Delegate method for blog parser will get fired when the process is completed

-(void)processCompleted
{
    NSLog(@"the rssItems array is %@", [[[self rssParser]rssItems] description]);
    int woeid = [[[[self rssParser] rssItems] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    // get weather update from yahoo
    NSLog(@"temperature option %d", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"temperature"] intValue]);
    SCYahooWeatherParser *parser = [[SCYahooWeatherParser alloc] initWithWOEID:woeid weatherUnit: [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"temperature"] intValue]];
    //parse the returned xml from yahoo
    SCWeather *result = [parser parse];
    [parser release];
    NSLog(@"the conditionDataDict is %@", [result.conditionDataDict description]);
}
```

How do I get the value returned by the `processCompleted` method, because I have called the `getWeather` Function.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective c, just like in any structured language, when you call a function that returns a value like in

```
NSInteger x = [self yourFunction];
[self somethingElse:x];
```

the next instruction is not executed until the function returns a value. In other words, somethingElse does not get executed until yourFunction has ended and returned a value for x.

Comment: My answer remains the same, please read throughly, you are not using any selectors or background threads, so the returned value is always obtained, no need to synchronize the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method, and pass waitUntilDone as Yes. It will wait for your function to complete-

```
performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
```

There are some more methods available, you can refer NSObject class - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

If your chain of functions is called in the main thread, your app should automatically wait for the process to end before going on and executing next operation. Then, you don't need to do anything to obtain your goal.

Please, note that if your process is very heavy, your app will freeze untill the end. It is a good custom executing processes that can block your app in another thread.